# Wrong WordPress links redirection

Tags: hyperlink, href, permalinks, location-href, broken-links

I have a WordPress web site and the site links was working good. For the last two days, suddenly found web site links redirect to the home page not the target link page. I checked the links code it's okay. I inspect links in the browser and I found this code changed for all links like this :

```
<a href="https://example.com" ohref="https://example.com/%d8%a5%d8%aa%d8%b5%d9%84-%d8%a8%d9%86%d8%a7/">اتصل بنا</a>
```

This means the right link code in `ohref` property and the alternative link code in `href` so all links open the main page for domain in href property.

What is the solution and what caused this problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

href="" is where the link is directing. ohref="" is a custom attr that can only work with a javascript function. So unless you have an on click listener with javascript it has no function.If there is a javascript function it will overwrite the href="" with a preventdefault()

Comment: the site was working .. suddenly heppen this issue .. what is the solution .. i am not good with javascript.

Comment: Try to change the href="" to the URL you are trying to make the link redirect to.

Comment: you mean write the link code again and test with update